# Write data from text file having two delimited to Excel using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have no knowledge of VBScript and need help.

Logically - I thought of splitting it with `#` in a for loop and then using `:` to split again.

Example:

Text file:

```
a : 21312 # asdfasd23sad : 43624 # asdsad*:21
```

Excel file:

[image]

Comment: So, soemthing not working with the approach you described? Are you getting errors? Please show your code and describe what is not working the way you expected. SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function arr()
input = a : 21312 # asdfasd23sad : 43624 # asdsad*:21
arr1 = Split(input, "#")

For i = Lbound(arr1) To Ubound (arr1)
 arr2 = Split(arr1(i),":")
 For j =  Lbound(arr2) To Ubound (arr2)
  Msgbox arr2(j)
 Next
Next
End function
```

Comment: Hi Ismail; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: Hi Ismail; I got this logic. Actually problem i am facing is to write this in excel file as shown in the screen shot.